# Projectile Motion, solving for initial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I'm stumped on a projectile motion launched from a cliff at an angle.
The only known values that are given are the height of the cliff $h$,
The total horizontal distance covered $d$ and the incline of the ramp $\theta$ and it asks to find the initial velocity $v_i$. How could I approach solving this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

I took another stab at it and I was able to solve it using the following equations: $$x_f=x_i+v_xt$$
$$y_f=y_i+v_y{_i}t +\frac 12at^2$$
Applying and rearranging these to my problem
For x-direction I get:
$$d=0+v_i\cos\theta\cdot t$$
$$v_i=\frac{d}{\cos\theta\cdot t}$$
And for y-direction:
$$0=h+v_i\sin\theta\cdot t -\frac 12gt^2$$
Apply previous equation and solve for $t$:
$$0=h+\frac{d\cdot \sin\theta\cdot t}{\cos\theta\cdot t} -\frac 12gt^2$$
$$0=h+d\cdot \tan\theta -\frac 12gt^2$$
$$\frac 12gt^2=h+d\cdot \tan\theta $$
$$t^2=2\cdot\frac{h+d\cdot \tan\theta}{g} $$
$$t=\sqrt{2\cdot\frac{h+d\cdot \tan\theta}{g}} $$
And finally, value for $t$ can be used in the first equation to solve for $v_i$.